# Accessing response data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I am using Jade and JavaScript. Server sends an array of objects `question` and I am able to access the array in HTML. But I not able to access it in JavaScript.

```
//This works.
select
    for q in question
        option(value= q.question_id)
            = q.text
```

```
for (q in question){
    var sub_q = document.createElement("DIV");
    var text_q = document.createTextNode(q.text);
    sub_q.appendChild(text_q);}
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: question is not defined
```

How can I access the data in javascript?
Thank you.

UPDATE:This is how I am rendering the data.

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        db.any("Select * from survey").then(function(data){callback(null, data)});
    },
    function(callback) {
        db.any("Select * from question").then(function(data){callback(null,data)});
    },
    function(callback) {
        db.any("Select * from answer").then(function(data){callback(null, data)});
    }
], function(err, results) {
    if(err)
        return console.log(err);
    console.log(results[1]);
    res.render('takesurvey',{ title: 'Take Survey', survey: results[0],question:results[1], answer:results[2]});
});
```

Comment: No `survey`, *"I am able to access the array in HTML."*

Comment: console.log the data in ajax response and see  what it display.. because you definitely have access to data in success function of ajax, there you can save data in some global variable

Comment: @Someone The error is for another array `survey` which I tried to access. :p

Comment: can you show where did you declare the variable question or did you pass it properly in your javascript file to jade

Comment: is your results[1] not undefined?

Comment: It is defined. The data is rendered and I can display it in the select element using the html code but I get the `ReferenceError` when using JS. Am I missing any concept?

Comment: @ashwinx There's no `question` array being defined and used in your actual code

Comment: (I mean, `question` should be defined and may be any kind of value)

Comment: @Someone I see what the problem is, the data gets rendered to Jade, it uses the data to produce HTML but I cant use it in client-side. FINALLY. Thanks for you time.